# Using enum in a model, when saving it doesn't like the integer value

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using rails 4.1.1

My model has an enum like:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum article_status: { published: 1, draft :2 }
```

Now in my new.html.erb I have:

```
<%= form.select :article_status, options_for_select(Article.article_statuses) %>
```

When going to save the model I get this error:

```
'1' is not a valid article_status
```

I was thinking it would be able to handle this during an update.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to pass the string of the enum rather than the integer value itself I believe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `update_attributes` or `new` call in your controllers will expect the stringified version of the enum symbol, not the integer.  So you need something like:

```
options_for_select(Article.article_statuses.
  collect{|item, val| [item.humanize, item]}, selected: @article.status)
```

There is a full example [in this article](http://richonrails.com/articles/active-record-enums-in-ruby-on-rails-4-1).